# Spring Data Rest vs Spring Data Rest WebMvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

What is the difference between:

```
spring-data-rest
```

and

```
spring-data-rest-webmvc
```

To obviously they are two different things, but I am slightly confused here.

Comment: MVC suggests a user interface; REST is a style for writing web services.  You can write REST web services without a user interrface, but it's likely that Spring Boot has created an opinionated package to make creating web MVC services that consume REST web services easy.

Answer (score 2):

The **spring-data-rest-webmvc** is the project describing the main concepts of **spring-data-rest** which is the one of the main spring modules.

In most cases one will use **spring-data-rest** dependency for his/her project.

Comment: Is there ever a usecase were I would use data-rest-webmvc over just data-rest?

Comment: In case where you start working with spring-data-rest and want to know how to start, as example (skeleton) for you project.

Answer (score 0):

Use **spring-data-rest** when your app is based on **Spring Boot**

**spring-data-rest-webmvc** when your app is **not** a Spring Boot app

Ref: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#install-chapter