# What is the difference between the various Spring Data Rest artifactids?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am specifically talking about the following.

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

The documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.boot) isn't very clear on the differences between [spring-boot-starter-data-rest](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.boot) and [spring-data-rest-webmvc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.maven). Is the difference essentially just the spring boot auto-configuration being included in the spring-boot-starter-data-rest artifact?

I assume that they both would include spring-data-rest-core at some point? How do I know which version of Spring Data REST WebMVC I would be using with spring-boot-start-data-rest?

I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999308/spring-data-rest-vs-spring-data-rest-webmvc) but doesn't directly answer my question.

Comment: Do you know what Spring Boot starters are generally? And do you know how to use `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @chrylis From my understanding they are basically the configuration for Spring. I was not familiar with `mvn dependency:tree`, but after looking at the output on my project and seeing where spring-boot-starter-data-rest is relative to the other dependencies it is slightly more clear.